# Recharts: Floating Bar Chart when another Bar has a stackId?

Tags: recharts

I want the first three values to be stacked on the first column.

I tried following [Creating ranged bar chart using recharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285884/creating-ranged-bar-chart-using-recharts) but having a custom shape didn't solve the problem.

The closest I could get is this configuration

[image]

```
      <Bar dataKey="value1" stackId="a" fill="#8884d8" />
      <Bar dataKey="value2" stackId="a" fill="#222" />
      <Bar dataKey="value3" stackId="a" fill="goldenrod" />
      <Bar dataKey="value4" fill="#58a0df" />
      <Bar dataKey="value5" fill="salmon" />
      <Bar dataKey="total" stackId="a" fill="#8908a7" />
```

Setting the stackId to be the same for all Bars makes it look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@piaseckimaks replied on my GitHub issue

A workaround was to create an invisible bar under the other bar.

```
<Bar dataKey="value4" stackId="a" fill="transparent" legendType="none" />
```

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "Column 1",
    value1: 3,
    value2: 2,
    value3: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Column 2",
    invisible: 6,
    value4: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Column 3",
    invisible: 10,
    value5: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Total",
    total: 11
  }
];
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/stacked-bar-chart-forked-jeuv0?file=/src/App.tsx:332-351

https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2524